# Fhir search by Identifier including property "use"

Tags: url, hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

I know how to search by the identifier's system and value in FHIR - `/Patient?identifier=123|system=https://nick.systems/try1`

But I am wondering if it's possible to include identifier.use property also.

For example I have two Patients with same system and value identifier. But first one has property "use":"old". Meaning it's not in use already.
So I want to exclude it from the search, smth like `/Patient?identifier=123|system=https://nick.systems/try1&identifier.use:not=old`

But I could not find any examples of it. I see that Patient search by Identifier uses token in URL, but maybe someone knows how to overpass it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The searching capabilities will depend on the FHIR server you are interacting with and what it supports. That said, your proposed search wouldn't do exactly what you want. Searching multiple values with AND logic will return the intersection of a search on each independent parameter. Thus, the portion of the search on `identifier.use` would not be restricted to identifiers with an `identifier.system` of `https://nick.systems/try1`.

You may want to look at [composite search parameters](https://hl7.org/fhir/search.html#composite) and [_filter](https://hl7.org/fhir/search_filter.html).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to define a custom search parameter that is either a composite or imposes custom filters on 'use.  There's no 'standard' search parameter that does what you're interested in.